# DNAT in Shorewall not working for VPN

Tags: vpn, shorewall, dnat

I have a firewall (10.8.0.1) connected to an internal server (10.8.0.2) via VPN. On the firewall the VPN interface is called `tun0`. So in my shorewall configuration I have this:

```
$ cat interfaces
#ZONE   INTERFACE   OPTIONS
-       lo          ignore
vpn     tun+        optional
net     eth+        dhcp,physical=+,routeback,optional

$ cat zones
#ZONE   TYPE        OPTIONS     IN          OUT
#                               OPTIONS     OPTIONS
fw      firewall
vpn     ipv4
net     ip

$ cat policy
#SOURCE DEST    POLICY      LOG LIMIT:      CONNLIMIT:
#               LEVEL       BURST           MASK
$FW     net     ACCEPT
$FW     vpn     ACCEPT
vpn     all     ACCEPT
net     all     DROP        info
```

Now I want to forward all traffic from the public net coming to TCP port 2222 on the firewall to the internal server port 22. So I have added the following two lines:

```
$ cat rules
ACCEPT          net         $FW                 tcp     2222
DNAT            net         vpn:10.8.0.2:22     tcp     2222
```

In my `shorewall.conf` file I have this line:

```
IP_FORWARDING=On
```

However, this does not seem to work.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

```
#
# Shorewall version 4 - Masq file
#

#INTERFACE:DEST         SOURCE              ADDRESS         PROTO   PORT(S) IPSEC   MARK    USER/   SWITCH
#                                           GROUP
tun+:10.8.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           10.8.0.1
```